# How can I clone an array to have alternative true and false fields?

Tags: python, list, memory

I can't wrap my head around how Python works with variables and lists - I want to clone a 50-element array into an 100 one, but to have each element followed by an element with the same values and fields, but `True` instead of `False` for one field.

```
global A
A = list()

for i in range(100):
    A.append(0)

index = 0

for i in range(50):
    A[index] = self.b[i]
    A[index + 1] = self.b[i]
    print ("It was " + str(A[index].f)) # always prints False
    print ("It was " + str(A[index + 1].f)) # always prints False
    A[index].f = False # pointless, but just making sure in my insanity 
    A[index + 1].f = True
    print ("This should be false: " + str(A[index].f)) # always prints True 
    print ("This should be true: " + str(A[index+1].f)) # always prints True as well
```

Comment: What is `self.b`?

Comment: It is a list passed to my file 
It contains the values I want for ```A```, with the exact same fields (same objects)

Comment: @EricSpataru But a list of *what*, though? This point is crucial to your question, since you're asking about cloning. Copying user-defined objects is not always straightforward.

Comment: Copying a user defined object to be more precise... I defined the whole thing in a separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists only hold references to objects; if you do

```
    A[index] = self.b[i]
    A[index + 1] = self.b[i]
```

then mutating `A[index]` or `A[index + 1]` or `self.b[i]` will all mutate the same object.

Using `deepcopy`, i.e.

```
    A[index] = self.b[i]
    A[index + 1] = copy.deepcopy(self.b[i])
```

will leave you with a separate copy for the other index.

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this without imports (this needs ```import copy```)?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid importing a builtin module?

Comment: it is required by my assignment - however, this is not even close to my original code, but an example I made up to better understand how mutable objects work in Python

Comment: Then you'd need to implement your own copy function.

Comment: Depending on your class, it could be as simple as (pardon the lack of indentation) `def copy(self): return self.__class__(a=self.a, b=self.b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally wrapped my head around it and it works wonders (I'm referring to the last addition you made without using imports)